# adding two javascript arrays together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that are built in exactly the same way that I need to add together.  One can be added to the end of the other, or a new array can be created containing the data of the two, it doesn't matter to me.

Here's a screenshot showing what this looks like NOW in Chrome's console:

[image]

## What I've Tried

I tried simply adding the two together...

```
var complete = [];
complete.push(array1);
complete.push(array2);
```

but this still leaves me with the upper `[Object, Object]` and `[Object, Object, Object]` levels that I'm trying to get rid of.

How do I merge the individual `Objects` from these arrays into one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `concat` function:

```
var complete = array1.concat(array2);
```

Comment: sweet - I knew there was a function like this, I just couldn't remember what it was called.  Thank you!  Worked like a charm :)

Comment: In case you wanted to fill out your clear and correct answer, `.push()` takes an element and pushes it onto the end of an array. That element might also be an array, but it is different than `concat()`.